# How to print inverted half-star pyramid pattern next to each other?

Tags: c++

I want to display an inverted half-star pyramid pattern next to each other.[Here's the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLyGc.png)

And here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n, x, y, k;
  cout << "Enter Number of Rows: ";
  cin >> n;
  for (x = n; x >= 1; x--)
  {
        for (y = 1; y <= x; y++)
        {
              if (y <= x)
                    cout << "*";
              else
                    cout << " ";
        }
        for (y = n; y >= 1; y--)
        {
              if (y <= x)
                    cout << "*";
              else
                    cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
```

}

[Here's the output I got after running the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDwgM.png)
The number of rows desired is 10.
After running my code, the output isn't like what I expected. Please tell me how to make it right.
Thank you.

Comment: Please show what output you get from your program for an input of 10.

Comment: think of it in that pattern: print 10 starts, 1 space, 10 stars, end line, 9 stars, 3 spaces, and 9 stars and so on. So you need to print 10 lines like that. You can capture 2 variables where you will store how much stars and spaces you will print in each line. So we can see that number of stars is decreasing one by one and number of spaces is increasing by 2 so you will need to update number of stars and spaces to print after each line. Hope it helps

Comment: Can you show it with code?

Answer (score 2):

I saw some symmetries in the problem

- for n rows, we're printing 2*n+1 characters
- for the yth row, we're printing an asterisk if x is less than n-y or more than n+y

So I coded a single double loop with the more complex *if* statement. I had to adjusted the *if* statement until it worked.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, x, y;
    cout << "Enter Number of Rows: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
    {
        for (x = 2*n+1; x > 0; x--)
        {
            if ((x > n+y+1) || (x < n-y+1))
                cout << "*";
            else
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to change your logic a little bit rest all is fine.

Here is the code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, x,  y, k;
    cout << "Enter the number of Rows: ";
    cin >> n;

    for(x = 1; x <= n; x++)
    {
        for(y = n; y >= 1; y--)
        {
            if(y <= x)
                cout << " ";
            else
                cout << "*";
        }

        for(y = 1; y <= n; y++)
        {
            if(y <= x)
                cout << " ";
            else
                cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation:- I am starting from row 1 and going till row "n". Now I need to print two different inverted flags so I used two for loops for that. In one loop I am starting from column "n" and going till row >1 and in the other loop, I am doing the just opposite of that so that both flags will be opposite to each other. Just try to understand this code by taking X as row and Y as column.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "changing the logic"?

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, really helpful!

Comment: Please [edit] the explanation into the answer.